# How to call an Oracle stored procedure with output parameters using doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, oracle11g, doctrine

I have been calling stored procs in Oracle using doctrine doing something like:

```
$sql = "CALL namespace.my_proc(".$data_source_id.", to_date('".$account_period_start."', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'".$updated_by."')";

$stmt = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('fdw')->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->closeCursor();
```

Now the DBA team has changed one of the stored procs to accept 2 output parameters (x and y) and I am not understanding how to make that happen. Can someone please assist me with that?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find out the info. Hope it helps someone.

```
$sql = "CALL namespace.my_proc(".$data_source_id.", to_date('".$account_period_start."', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'".$updated_by."', :x, :y)";
  $stmt = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('fdw')->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':x', $x, \PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 32);
            $stmt->bindParam(':y', $y, \PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 32);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

For most recent versions of doctrine:

```php
$sql = 'call my_proc(:arg1, :arg2)';
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->executeQuery([
    ':arg1' => 82,
    ':arg2' => 'Foo',
]);
```

However, for output parameters you apply the same logic for functions:

```php
$sql = 'BEGIN :total := sum(:num1, :num2); END;';
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':total', $total);
$stmt->executeQuery([
    ':num1' => 6,
    ':num2' => 7
]);
```

`$total` will store the output